# Inkscape - I want to import another svg file to its own layer and I cannot make it work

Tags: inkscape

I have several svg files that originated as pdfs produced by R. These have been edited ikn Inkscape and now I need to combine them into one svg file ready for publication.
I have layer one - just a background. I added the bar plot layer, copied the bar plot and it went onto its own layer. If I close the eye, the plot disappears. All good.

To bring in the next file, I did the same - made a new layer - nj.tree, had it selected but as soon as I do Ctrl +V, the active layer in the bottom left of the screen becomes [root], and the tree is not on its own layer. Closing the eyes on all layers does not hide the tree.
Any idea what I am doing wrong please?[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this myself.

Have the layer I want made.
Select the object that you want to shift to the layer, right click and select "Move to layer" and pick the layer you want.